# is naming the unique constraint with multiple columns significant?

Tags: mysql

Suppose i have a table customers having multiple fields. I am considering, three fields to be unique :date of birth, phone number, mail id. in order to create this table, the create script would be:

```
create table customers(
customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(255),
last_name VARCHAR(255),
address VARCHAR(255),
DOB datetime Not NULL,
phone_number int(10) NOT NULL,
email_address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
UNIQUE KEY (customer_id,DOB,phone_number,email_address)
);
```

however i have noticed that unique key is declared with a name - UNIQUE KEY customer_id (customer_id,DOB,phone_number,email_address).
I need help in understanding why and when the unique constraint to be named, and what value would it add? Also what is the best practice for naming?

(Note:I do understand the concept of UNIQUE INDEX, but here i want to understand the naming of UNIQUE constraint)

Comment: Adding `customer_id` to your unique key does not make any sense.

Comment: To take a step back, I disagree with your unique constraint.  It would allow each of the three columns to appear in more than one record.  Ideally, a phone number or email should only be associated with a single user (the birthdate can, obviously, be associated with more than one user).  To your actual question: naming the unique constraint makes it easier to do something like removing it by name.

Comment: Each constraint must have unique name. Each index must have unique name. If the name is not specified in SQL statement it is generated automatically.

In general autocreated index name includes the name of the first field in the index expression as a prefix, and numbering suffix for to avoid the index name duplication.

Comment: thank you, this helps @Akina. please ignore the fields considered. thanks for the advice though